# Sort the values of first list using second list with different length in Python

Tags: python, pandas, text-extraction, string-length

I have a data with a column with some words. i extracted some words by list of words, for example ingredients_list=['water','milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']. This is the list with right order of words and each word should be sorted by this order.
When i extracted words, i create a Series of extracted words, but some rows in this series contains two word or no words. For example (actual length of a series is 25000):

| index | ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | sugar |
| 1 | yeast |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | ananas milk |
| 4 | sugar water |
| 5 | milk |

what i want is to order those rows which contains two words, such as in index 3 and 4, by the order of ingredients_list. For example:

| index | ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | sugar |
| 1 | yeast |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | milk ananas |
| 4 | water sugar |
| 5 | milk |

First what i did is to replace empty rows with 'unknown".
Then i tried some codes:

```
ingredients_list=['water','milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']
path = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in ingredients_list)
ing_l = df['ingredients'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(' ')
ing_l= ing_l.replace("","Unknown")

then to sort them accordingly to ingredients_list:

def sort_list(list1, list2):
    zipped_pairs = zip(list2, list1)
    z = [x for _, x in sorted(zipped_pairs)] 
    return z

words = sort_list(ing_l, ingredients_list)

OR

d = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(ing_l)}
r = sorted(ingredients_list, key=lambda v: d[v])
```

But what i got is a list of length of 6, as ingredients_list length.
Then i try:

```
ing_l= pd.DataFrame(ing_l)
ing_l['sort'] = [word for x in ingredients_list for word in ing_l if word == x]
```

But i have some error ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (25000)
Do you have any solution to this problem? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `apply` `sorted` with a custom dictionary on the split string and `join` again:

```
ingredients_list=['water','milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']

order = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(ingredients_list)}

df['sorted_ingredients'] = (
  df['ingredients']
  .str.split()
  .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x, key=order.get)) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
 )
```

output:

```
   index   ingredients sorted_ingredients
0       0        sugar              sugar
1       1        yeast              yeast
2       2          NaN                NaN
3       3  ananas milk        milk ananas
4       4  sugar water        water sugar
5       5         milk               milk
```