# How to extract list of words out of a string with no spaces

Tags: python, extract, text-extraction

I have a dataset and one of the column contains sentences, in some of sentences the words are stucking together. i want to extract this words if there appears on each row. ingredients_list=['water','milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']. I use this code for extracting the words

```
ingredients_list=['water','milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']
path = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in ingredients_list)
ing_l = df['ingredients'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(' ')
ing_l= ing_l.replace("","Unknown")
```

Its works great but, it didn't extract words from ingredients_list, if one of the words are stuck with another, i mean in a sentence "breadmilkcoffee" it fails to extract "milk" among this stucking words.
I asking a related question for helping me to order the words i extract, [Sort the values of first list using second list with different length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632620/sort-the-values-of-first-list-using-second-list-with-different-length-in-python) .
But i didn't extract all the words.
Do you have any solution to this problem? Thank you a lot

Comment: maybe you mean ingredients_list=['water,milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas'] ?

Comment: Hi, one of the column contains sentences and i want to extract words from these sentences if they match the words from ingredients_list=['water,milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `\b` special character, which asserts that the pattern appears at a word boundary.

Removing this should allow you to match items in `ingredients_list` when they are not separated by a space from the rest of the string.

```py
ingredients_list=['water','milk', 'yeast', 'banana', 'sugar', 'ananas']
path = '|'.join(r"{}".format(x) for x in ingredients_list)
ing_l = df['ingredients'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(' ')
ing_l= ing_l.replace("","Unknown")
```